# Vertically and Horizontally Center Text in an Image regardless of Resolution Proportions

Tags: jquery, html, css

I would like to vertically and horizontally center text into a image. I don't care if it is pure HTML/CSS or not.

So far I have tried this solution which I found on StackOverflow:

```css
.image {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%; /* for IE 6 */
}

h2 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 200px;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```css
<body>
    <div class="image">
        <img src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png">
        <h2>Text</h2>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: @Pekka I can't find anything that shows how to center vertically and horizontally.

Comment: you can find something really helpful here https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/

Comment: @SkylerSpaeth please, don't use the comments section to showcase what you tried and what's your current code you're having issues with. [edit] your question instead to add the minimal code to reproduce your issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try utilizing `css` `:before` pseudo-element , `calc()`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    .image {
      position: relative;
      width: 100%;
      /* for IE 6 */
    }
    .image:before {
      position: absolute;
      left: calc(538px / 2 - 12px);
      top: calc(190px / 2 - 12px);
      width: 24px;
      content: "Text";
      display: block;
      font-size: 1.5em;
      font-weight: bold;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="image">
    <img src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png">
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Is there an alternative that doesn't fail? Very few people will be accessing this on Android. Primarily iOS, Mac or Windows.

Comment: There's a couple of approaches. For IE9+ a `transform: translate' then for deeper support negative margins and lastly JavaScript. A bit too much to post in a comment. The pseudo element solution is nice in itself. Edit - or direct pixel placement like the previous comment.

Comment: @guest271314 Ok. Is there any way for it not to be based off of resolution? Rather just center?

Comment: @SkylerSpaeth _"Is there any way for it not to be based off of resolution? Rather just center?"_ ? Not certain interpret comment correctly ? "center" of ? See OP at _"Vertically and Horizontally Center Text in an Image"_ ?

Comment: You maybe mean it should be responsive? What browser support exactly? I see style for IE6...

Comment: I would like to be able to use any image, regardless of it resolution proportions, and have text be centered _within the image_. @guest271314@Shikkediel

Comment: I'd go with a transform. Can be used *with* the pseudo element here. Has pretty much the same support as `calc()` but Android included. http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d

Comment: @SkylerSpaeth _"I would like to be able to use any image, regardless of it resolution proportions, and have text be centered within the image."_ not appear at Question ? See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

I like the previous pseudo element approach so I'll post another solution based on it but with deeper browser support and responsiveness (see comments) :

```
.image {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.image:after {
  content: "Text";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-weight: bold;
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KddrOZ?editors=110